# Trigger Plugin without modifying/creating an entity record

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, dynamics-crm, crm

How can I trigger a plugin via javaScript without modifying/creating an entity record. What I have now is I created a custom entity that will trigger my plugin. Every time the user clicks on button it will create a new record to the custom entity.
So instead of this logic I'm searching of any way to do this.

The main logic here is that when a user clicks on the button it should display a view with dynamic filter, so in my plugin I want to modify the criteria of my view based on the CRM current record, below link is my resources to change the criteria of view through C#, 
[Modify CRM View Query or Filter Criteria on Demand Dynamically using Plugin Retrieve](https://missdynamicscrm.blogspot.com/2016/05/modify-crm-view-query-or-filter-dynamically-plugin-retrieve-message-crm-csharp.html?showComment=1470213636218#c4871052886255733362)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That link you posted will register the query in the Retrieve message, so it would apply for anyone pulling data for that entity. It doesn't create any records, it just returns what the plugin returns.

Every plugin will be invoked from a message, like Create, Update, Associate, Retrieve etc. So it is not possible to call a plugin directly from Javascript.

You could call workflows tho, but it would be messy to retrieve the response because you need to store the query results generated by the workflow somewhere.

If you are using CRM 2016, it will be possible to call custom C# code called (Custom Actions) from Javascript.

Are you sure you can't implement the filter you need, which is based on a CRM record, via an out of the box subgrid filter, for example, or a custom filter from Javascript?

Comment: I'm trying to filter the activity view where regardingobjectid is equal to the selected account, In my form I have a button which will open the view via javascript, but the out of the box view allows only to set the regardingobjectid by default value, so every time I navigate to other account and open the view it display the record I set by default which is not what I want.